# Regex exclude a folder from node_modules

Tags: regex, webpack

I am currently using webpack and running a test that goes through node_modules and excludes one specific module.

However, i am struggling with the regular expression as i am trying it on the regex checker, and it works fine. However, on the webpack it fails.

**Example**: https://regex101.com/r/rO4jD0/34

```
^node_modules\/(?!example).*
```

On the webpack itself, i am writing the following:

```
vendor: {
    test: /^[\\/]node_modules[\\/](?!example).*[\\/]/,
    // test: /^[\\/]node_modules[\\/](?!example)[\\/].*/,
    // test: /^node_modules\/(?!example).*/,
    name: 'vendor',
    chunks: 'all',
}
```

The tests are examples of the tests i've run so far but unfortunately all of them failed.

**As an FYI** - this works fine but it **doesnt** exclude that one **example** folder.

```
test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
```

Comment: Are you complety sure your output string starts with __node_modules__? remember **^** asserts at the start of the string (happened to me once, that's why i'm asking)

Answer (score 5):

Is this to split out a large vendor module into its own bundle? Here is how I did that:

```
vendor: {
  name: 'vendor',
  test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]((?!(example.js|slick-carousel)).*)[\\/]/,
  name: 'vendors',
  chunks: 'all'
},
v_example: {
  test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]((example.js).*)[\\/]/,
  name: 'v_example',
  chunks: 'all'
},
v_slick: {
  test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]((slick-carousel).*)[\\/]/,
  name: 'v_slick',
  chunks: 'all'
}
```